Covered up hydronic baseboard heat, advise needed
I have hydronic baseboard heat that is partially hidden within my kitchen island. I did add those metal vents to allow some of the heat to escape and warm up the kitchen. Researching how these hydronic baseboards work, it essentially needs colder air to pass the bottom of the baseboard and then it warm up on the baseboards fins. The air get warmer and rises.
The problem am seeing is that the metal vents themselves get warm but I dont see that upward pressure from the heat. For example other heat baseboards that are not covered up there's an upward pressure of warm air. You can sometimes see this when the curtains near the baseboard began to move. This particular hidden baseboard in the kitchen has no such pressure.
I was wondering is its worth drilling some 1/4 holes at bottom of the baseboard on the wood. The holes would be horizontal with the goal being that it would attract colder air and allow warmer air to rise up through the vents. Something that is not happening now.
I wanted to get ideas from individuals on here that know a lot more about this than I do. Is my thinking correct, and would this help. Right now I feel like the vents at warm but warm air is not being released into the room from the vents. I also believe this is causing the baseboards down the line from these vents to not become as hot.
Any advise on this would be greatly appreciated.
Paul


I would find a narrow metal register cover, cut out the base as close to the floor as possible and mount the cover into the opening. If you can cut the lip from the bottom of the register to lower the profile, even better.

First, adding a grill or two along the face and/or ends would be more effective and look better than drilling a few holes. Whether additional grills would be sufficient is hard to tell from here:

How much additional heat is needed? What is the temperature difference between that part of the kitchen and other rooms?
How well insulated is the kitchen? Is the convector pouring heat into an area where it's quickly dissipated?
What is the temperature and length of the convector under that cover? Is there sufficient temperature difference to drive convection?
What is the heat flow (water flow and temperature) available there?

Second, there are booster fans such as these at Home Depot and hydronic baseboard convectors with fans such as these at Amazon, shown as an examples only. They require access to electricity.
Personally, I'd add passive grills first, and if that didn't provide enough heat, try a fan.

I might use some round 2 inch registers. However, do you think my theory is correct and by adding the grill the heat rise up and therefore work better. I dont just want to add the register/grill i want to make sure my theory is correct. thanks for taking the time to and answer my question.

Your theory is valid. Whether there is enough differential in temperature to cause sufficient convection for your needs in the kitchen is hard to know, though.
